How to boot into a specific recovery partition on an M1 Mac Mini that has both macOS Sequoia and Asahi Linux installed?
I have an M1 Mac Mini that has both macOS Sequoia and Asahi Linux installed on the internal drive, in separate APFS containers, each with its own recovery partition.
However, the boot menu (power button long press) only shows one recovery option, and that is the Asahi's recovery partition.
Is it possible to boot specifically from the macOS' paired recovery partition?
FWIW, the reason I want to do this is I want to adjust the security policy for the macOS install, which isn't possible from the Asahi recovery partition, which is paired with the Asahi stub partition.

After some experimenting I found out that switching the default boot volume via "Startup Disk" in macOS itself will also switch which recovery partition appears as the only "Recovery" in the boot menu to that OS' paired recovery partition.

Nice work - thanks for coming back and explaining what you did't initially realize was something that would change over recovery options.
